# Need to create a dummy variable in R that is equal to 1 if the variable name contains specific phrases

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I want to create a new variable, created_idx_var, that is equal to 1 if the variable name contains any of the phrases "idx", "Idx", "indx", "Indx", "index", "Index", "etf", "ETF", or if the variable index equals "Yes".

I just started to learn R. My first step is to eliminate the dataset and keep only equity funds. Then I want to create a flag to see if a fund is an index fund. I searched online but couldn't find anything.

Some of the sample data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30ASN.png)

This is my code so far.

```
library(readxl)
mydata <- read_excel("C:/category.xlsx",sheet = 1)
utils::View(mydata)
mydata <- subset(mydata, global_group=="Equity")
```

Comment: can you share some code (even code that doesn't work) to make it easier to imagine what you're up to?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for reference.

Comment: please look at `%in%`

Comment: @Hayley Han, you should provide data sample from C:/category.xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a vector of values:

```
x = c("idx", "a", "b","c", "Index")
```

Then you can create a binary vector as you mentioned which have `1` if match any string from the list `(idx|Idx|indx|Indx|index|Index|etf|ETF)` or `0` otherwise:

```
result = sapply(x, function(x) ifelse(grepl("idx|Idx|indx|Indx|index|Index|etf|ETF", x) == 1, 1, 0))
```

Comment: No need for `ifelse()`. You could simply do `+sapply(x, function(x) grepl("idx|Idx|indx|Indx|index|Index|etf|ETF", x))` or `+stringi::stri_detect_regex(x, "idx|Idx|indx|Indx|index|Index|etf|ETF")`